# What is the name of logic which considers several distinct undefined objects?

Tags: logic, terminology

Here is an example of a sentence of set theory written in first-order logic

> $\forall w_1\forall w_2\forall w_3\forall x \exists ! y\text{ } \phi(x,w_1,w_2,w_3)$
>
> (where $\phi$ is a definable sentence)

In above example, each letter such as $x,y,w_i$ denotes a single type of object, named set.

> **Question** : Is there a logic which considers two type of objects simultaneously?

That is, let $x^A$ denote $A$-type of object and $x^B$ denote $B$-type of object.

Hence, a sentence in this logic would look like $\forall x^A\forall y^B \forall w_1^A \forall w_2^B \exists z^A \text{ } \phi(x^A,y^B,w_1^A,w_2^B,z^A)$

What is this logic called?

I guessed this would be called something like "multi-valued first order logic" but it seems like that term is being used for another type of logic.

An example I know is NBG which considers set & class simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is many-sorted logic (or two-,three-,etc. in the concrete cases).

These logics have several distinct type of objects, or sorts. For example, vector spaces can be easily formalized in a two-sorted logic, where we have one sort for the scalars (and the underlying field) and one sort for vectors.

- [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic)
- [PlanetMath entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic)

On the other hand, multi-valued logic is a logic where the truth values have more than just the classical true/false values. Those can be three-valued logic, Boolean-valued logic, or all sort of intuitionistic logics (whose truth values are often considered from a Heyting algebra).

Comment: I think "typed" is also used as a synonym of "many-sorted". Of course, these considerations have close ties to type theory.

Comment: I prefer not to have close ties with type theory. For the same reason my choice of programming languages were assembly (everything is binary data, including compiled code) and Common Lisp (everything is a list, including the code!)